# Could not load file or assembly ‘GridRuntimeDOM_managed.dll ‘ or one of its dependencies . The specified module could not be found

Tags: ansible

i am uploading this in hopes that someone can actually give me an answer/solution .

So I am using ansible to deploy virtual machines and to run several tasks on each virtual machine , and one of the tasks is to download certain file using its installer , the issue that I’m having is simple , when I try to run the ansible playbook to download the chosen files on my virtual machine I am getting the following error : “ could not load file or assembly ‘ gridRuntimeDOM_managed.dll’ or one of its dependencies . The specified module could not be found.

But surprisingly, when I run the exact same command to download the chosen file manually on my virtual machine, it works perfectly.

Now I have tried everything trying to solve this issue , I have checked the environment variables , I have checked also the DLL dependencies using the depends tool , I have tried also a lot of ways in order to try to solve this issue but still nothing.

I hope that somebody can give me an answer or a solution to this.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried everything trying to solve this issue , I have checked the environment variables , I have checked also the DLL dependencies using the depends tool , I have tried also a lot of ways in order to try to solve this issue but still nothing.